# How to migrate my dbt incremental model to azure synapse?

Tags: azure-synapse, dbt, incremental-build

so i am doing a universty project that is suppposed to create an incremental(merging in sql) data loading process on the cloud

i am using python/dbt/sql-server
and currently the model is working quite fine on sql server
but now that i have to migrate it to azure synapse i am no exactly sure where to start i know there is a synapse adapter for dbt but should i use serverless or dedicated sql pools?
do i have to change my T-SQL can i do merges on synapse?
i really would love if someon could give me some help

Comment: "Dedicated" is the name for the relational part of Synapse. You need dedicated. Then try deploying and see what errors you get. A lot of features and syntax is different.

Comment: To use Synapse properly there is an entire tuning and design process that needs to be undertaken. Synaspe dedicated is really built for tables with billions of records.

Answer (score 0):

The dbt sql server adapter is enhanced to be able to access Azure SQL database as well and not just On Prem SQL server.
There are SQL auth,AD auth, Service principal auth and CLI auth.

So in case if the amount of data is less (< 1 tb), I would suggest moving to Azure SQL database thereby there wont be any major change w.r.t DBT.

In case if you move to synapse, it would add to a huge amount and also there might be some syntactical changes in your queries.